# Neo4j - Unit testing REST Api calls

Tags: unit-testing, rest, nosql, neo4j

I'm about to use Neo4j Server (Rest Api).

I've thought to the way of unit testing Neo4j.

I found [NoSqlUnit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit) that play the same role as DbUnit but dedicated to NoSql database like Neo4j.

However, main solutions are easy to set up for those who use the embbeded version of Neo4J (in plain Java, Scala ..).

Is there an effective way to unit test Rest Api calls thanks to an embedded database substitution?

**UPDATE ----------------------**

Sorry, I misread the NoSqlUnit documentation. 
It seems that an effective way would be to create an embedded database wrapped by a server. That is, Rest API calls will point on `localhost`. Pretty for unit testing.

Comment: And you might want to use the org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel, type:test-jar dependency for our in-memory ImpermanentGraphDatabase

Comment: @Michael Hunger Thanks, I see the presentation page: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html  but how to "mock" or "stub" rest api's calls? Do I need to use a wrapper who masks rest api like https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/ before using your tool?

Comment: @Michael Hunger I come across your great document calls "Good relationships". Yesterday, I spent my time to search for a great rest client and a good way of testing it... I didn't hear about Spring data for Neo4j which can carries about all these things + huge additional good things:) Great !

Comment: actually a ImpermanentGDB wrapped by a server :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org.neo4j.harness` which contains `newInProcessBuilder()`

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions-testing.html

Second options is to use `TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase()`

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html

last but not least (and the best one) is to use GraphUnit

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/tests#graphunit