# How to unit test Neo4j with Scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, neo4j

I need to test some Neo4J queries in my unit/integration tests with Scala.

Is there any way to do it? the only solution is Neo4j embbeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend to test against embedded or use the embedded option. If you have the chance to try the latest Neo4J, version +3.0, you will be able to get a performance improvement as version +3.0 introduced the [Bolt protocol](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/index.html#term-bolt) .

Prior to 3.0 you had to either use the REST endpoints, that you can easily test using scalatest,etc..., or go with the embedded option, which is explicitly discouraged as stated in the documentation. Other libraries are available, such as Anormcypher, to access Neo4j prior to 3.0v.

If you are able to use +3.0 you can use the Java API  https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver

There is a similar question available at SO: [Neo4j - Unit testing REST Api calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350021/neo4j-unit-testing-rest-api-calls?rq=1)

Comment: I am using the 3.0v and I would like to use the Bolt protocol respect to the Rest API. Can it be "mocked" in some way?